# How to select rows with 10% of the votes here?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "votes" "perCent"
"4177"  "3"     "4176"      "US"        "105"   "0"// total of all the below
"4178"  "10"    "4177"      "US"        "15"    "0"
"4179"  "10"    "4177"      "US"        "50"    "0"
"4180"  "10"    "4177"      "US"        "25"    "0"
"4181"  "10"    "4177"      "US"        "5"     "0"
"4182"  "10"    "4177"      "US"        "10"    "0"
```

In MySQL, is it possible to select rows that have 10% of the votes. Over here, `id = 4177` has the total votes for that category. Based on that, can the ones where `type = 10 and parent = 4177` and which have `10% or more` of the votes be selected?

Comment: What is the problem. What you have done?

Comment: `select id from table where type = 10 and votes >= 10% of total votes` si what I'm trying to do. The total votes are in `id=4177`. Possible to do something like this?

Comment: If total vote is 4177, then the 10% of total vote is 417.7. Is I am right.

Comment: No. Total votes are in column `votes` = `105`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/445e1/1)

```
SELECT *
FROM Votestable v
WHERE v.votes > (SELECT
                   votes
                 FROM Votestable v1
                 WHERE v1.id = v.parent) * 0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM myTable v
WHERE 
 v.Type = 10
 AND  0.1 < v.Votes / (SELECT MAX(m.votes) FROM myTable m WHERE m.Type = 3 AND m.Id = t.Parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
select id from table where type =10 and votes>=(votes/100)*10;
```

Comment: I think the calculation is ok .

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned 105 as total votes ,

```
select * , ((votes * 100) / 105) as percent
from votesTable
where ((votes * 100) / 105) > 10.0 and type=10 and parent = 4177
```